# 2 or more users trying to upload the same data at the same time

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to develop a hairdressing application. But i have a problem when two or more users try to upload the same data (a String with the appointment time) at the same time. How can I get only 1 of them to upload the data?. I´m using Firebase (FireStore) and Android Studio with Java.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use a [transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#value_type_ordering) to ensure that two client apps don't overwrite each other's changes.  The code in the transaction will need to know how to check if work has already been done, and what to do if that's the case.

Comment: Any idea about how to do the last part? xD

Comment: Go to the linked documentation to learn more.  Your problem description isn't specific enough to give any more advice. If you have specific problems with implementation, please post a new question that describes what you're trying to accomplish, and the code with the code that isn't working the way you expect.